# JPA/Hibernate 4 - getting ScrollableResults

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate 4.2 as my JPA provider.
I want to use a ScrollableResults object to process my result set.

My code looks like this, essentially:

```
javax.persistence.Query q = em.createQuery(...);
org.hibernate.Query query = ((org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl)q).getHibernateQuery();
query.setParameter(blah blah);
ScrollableResults sr = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
```

This always throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.IntegerTypeDescriptor.unwrap(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:608)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1870)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1831)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1811)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2516)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2502)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2332)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2327)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at com.example.server.ChartGenerator.getChart()
```

As an experiment, replacing query.scroll() with query.list() also produces the same exception.

The QueryImpl type is a raw type, but I can't figure out what to put in there, or if that's even what the problem is.

My query returns a date followed by several ints; it does not map directly to a class.  I just want an array of objects - I have loads of data to process, and mapping to objects will just slow me down!

Comment: Oops, my listed exception is for the query.list() test, not the query.scroll().  Same result, though.

Comment: Another update:  calling  query.getReturnTypes()  returns the correct types for my query.

Comment: What's the query, and what are the relevant entities and their mapping?

Comment: what are the parameters that you are setting? the exception happen when it bind the parameters

Comment: The query is:  SELECT row.date, row.delay, row.jitter FROM Metrics row WHERE {clauses}.   This query runs successfully when I use JPA's query.getResultList().

Comment: Ah,thanks fmodos... that's down the right track.  My clauses include "WHERE row.groupid in ( :groupids )"  and I am setting groupids to an ArrayList<Integer>.  Using "WHERE row.groupid=:groupid"  and setting a single integer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a good tip from fmodos, the exception was arising because I was calling:

```
org.hibernate.Query.setParameter("groupids", list);
```

The problem is resolved by calling one of the following:

```
org.hibernate.Query.setParameterList("groupids", list);
javax.persistence.Query.setParameter("groupids", list);
```